# BroadcastReceiver Service, сервис сам отключается в фоне

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver

Добрый день. Такая проблема написал service, который в фоне собирает координаты с GPS. Проблема в чем когда gps включен на телефоне, приложение работает и собирает координаты даже если убить приложение бэксервис отрабатывает, но как только gps на устройстве выключается, то и сервис умирает и при обратном включении gps сервис не запускается(П.С. обратным включением просто проверял, вдруг сервис не умер, а лег спать).
Бродкастресивер ниже

```
 public class GPSReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.
        Log.wtf("backservice","in RECIEVER");

        context.startService(new Intent(context,GPSService.class));
    }
}
```

Код Сервиса который ловит гпс в фоне

```
    public class GPSService extends Service {
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;

    private DBHelper dbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public GPSService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.wtf("backservice", "permissions denied");
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000 * 10, 10, locationListener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000 * 10, 10, locationListener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, 1000 * 10, 10, locationListener);
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Log.wtf("backservice", "Notification manager enabled" + notificationManager.toString());
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
        dbHelper.close();
        Log.wtf("backservice", "GPSService Destroyed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        //super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        dbHelper.close();
        startService(new Intent(this, getClass()));
        Log.wtf("backservice", "GPSService TASKREMOVED!");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {



        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        }else {

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000 * 10, 10, locationListener);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000 * 10, 10, locationListener);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, 1000 * 10, 10, locationListener);
        }

        Log.wtf("backservice", "GPS service is started call from onStartCommand");

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(GPSService.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(GPSService.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Notification.Builder nb = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext()).setTicker("have no permissions for gps")
                    .setContentText("Please give permissions to use ur gps")
                    .setContentTitle("Need some permissions");
            Intent fIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, fIntent, 0);
            nb.setContentIntent(pIntent)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
            Notification nf = nb.build();
            notificationManager.notify(0, nf);
            return START_NOT_STICKY;
        }
        locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        return START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY;
    }

    private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put("latitude",location.getLatitude());
            cv.put("longitude",location.getLongitude());
            cv.put("stamp",location.getTime());

            long rawId = db.insert("positions",null,cv);

            Log.wtf("backservice", "onlocation changed" + location.toString());
            Log.wtf("backservice","ID in database->"+rawId);



        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            switch (provider) {
                case LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER:
                    Log.wtf("backservice", "GPS provider status changed to " + status);
                    if(status!= LocationProvider.AVAILABLE){
                        Log.wtf("backservice","GPS IS UNVALIABLE, so from there we can send data to back");
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER:
                    Log.wtf("backservice", "Network provider status changed to " + status);
                    break;
                case LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER:
                    Log.wtf("backservice", "Passive provider status changed to " + status);
                    break;
            }
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

                Log.wtf("backservice","Permissions denied");
            }else{
                Log.wtf("backservice", "Call from StatusChanged:"+String.valueOf(locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider)));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            switch (provider) {
                case LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER:
                    Log.wtf("backservice", "GPS ENABLED");
                    break;
                case LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER:
                    Log.wtf("backservice", "NETWORK PROVIDER ENABLED");
                    break;
                case LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER:
                    Log.wtf("backservice", "PASSIVE PROVIDER ENABLED");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

            }
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

                Log.wtf("backservice","Permissions denied");
            }else{
                Log.wtf("backservice", "Call from ProviderEnabled"+String.valueOf(locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider)));
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            switch (provider){
                case LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER:
                    Log.wtf("backservice","GPS DISABLED");
                    break;
                case LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER:
                    Log.wtf("backservice","NETWORK PROVIDER DISABLED");
                    break;
                case LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER:
                    Log.wtf("backservice","PASSIVE PROVIDER DISABLED");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        return null;
    }
}
```

И сам манифест

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="kz.dokazhi.sendinggps"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <receiver
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"

            android:name="kz.dokazhi.sendinggps.services.GPSReciever">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".services.GPSService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=":gpsproc"/>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Объясните пожалуйста, почему так происходит и как это исправить.

Comment: Добавите в  onCreate startForeground(). статья на хабре по сервисам https://habrahabr.ru/post/265159/

Comment: Читал, и там про нотификацию, подобие плеера в док панеле. Плюс чтобы стартануть service в foregrounde необходима минимальная версия андроида Орео. и Вопрос был в том, что сервис сам собой просто исчезает.

Comment: Почему Oreo нужно? насколько мне известно foreground очень давно уже есть, только с Doze  проблемы. Сам по себе он исчезнуть не может, его система убивает, чтобы такого не было более или менее foreground помогает, сам делал, работает

Comment: А почему бы ему не изчезнуть он же не foregrounde ?  Его система может легко при требование ресурсов выкосить. Да и для startForeground не нужен Oreo. startForeground появился в api level 5.

Comment: внесу свои 5 копеек - проблемы с Doze при WiFi, если инет мобильный Doze не проблема.

Comment: ребят, это же сервис, я делаю startForegroundService, так как это сервис. А startForeground  относиться к notification объекту. Может быть кто-нибудь сможет объяснить как мне "запихнуть" сервис в объект  notification?

Comment: Засунул через foregroundService, открыв notification и сервис все равно в течении 5 минут выключается

Answer (score 1):

Добавь этот код в oncreate сервиса

```java
//Создание уведомления
 String CHANNEL_ID = "Идентификатор уведомлений";
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID).
            setSmallIcon(R.drawable.).setContentTitle("заголовок").
            setContentText("текст").setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MIN);
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "Название в настройках", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
//Включение foreground и показ уведомления
    startForeground(150, builder.build());
```